# Did the searchTwitter() in twitteR stop working?

Tags: r, twitter

I just reran an old script where I used the commands...

```
> library(twitteR)
> searchTwitter("#beer", n=100) # directly from the ?help
list()
```

However, for all queries and param combinations, I'm getting an empty list---but no error message to speak of.  Did this function get deprecated, either by twitteR or through the twitter API itself?  (Or is it just me?)

Comment: Did you go through the API authentication process?

Comment: No, but I didn't in my original code, either.  I just reran code that used to work---this was optional before.  Is it the case that this is now mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Twitter deprecated allowing an unauthenticated user to query tweets moving from its 1.0 API to the 1.1 API, and now requires all users authenticate.  The function probably used to call the 1.0 form, but this is no longer possible.

So, the `searchTwitter()` function now requires additional authentication to return the results it used to.  This is why the function call that used to work now returns an empty list.

This change appears to have [taken place within the last year](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api).